gdal_calc.py expression to extract where raster is equal to 2 values
I am trying to extract all raster values where the cell is equal to either 330 or 430, however I can't get the syntax to work. I am using the following:
python gdal_calc.py --co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" --co "TILED=YES" --co "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS" -A raster.tif --outfile=output_raster.tif --calc="A*logical_or(A=330,A=430)"

Is anyone able to advise?

Are you missing a dash from --calc=<expression>?

Sorry, a typo. I've corrected it, but the problem remains. Thanks

--calc="A*logical_or(A==330,A==430)"

Thanks Robert Davy, that has done the trick
